# Install Slim 3.x manually

Tags: php, installation, frameworks, slim

I want to use Slim 3.x framework to create a REST API for my applications.

I am using a shared hosting, so I can't use composer to install dependencies, therefore I have to install it manually.

I followed [this](http://www.codediesel.com/php/how-to-manually-install-slim-framework/) tutorial, but I can't figure out how to change these lines in my `index.php` file to make it work!

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

and also this one:

```
use \Slim\Slim;

Slim::registerAutoloader();
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you installed was Slim 2.x.

Comment: @geggleto yes, but i can't find out how to use Slim 3.x manually. is it possible or not?

Comment: Only way that I know is to develop everything locally and upload your project with it's dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle Composer dependencies is to run Composer locally and commit the vendor directory into your repository.

Write your website, using Composer, as usual and commit `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and all the files in `vendor`.

Note the following:

1. Ensure that your `.gitignore` file does not exclude `vendor`. This is very common when starting from a skeleton project.
   2, Ensure that you only use packages that have a release number. That is never use `dev-master` in your `composer.json` as if you do, Composer will install it via git and you won't be able to add it to your own repository. There are good reasons for [avoiding dev-master dependencies](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2015/relying-on-a-dev-master-dependency-in-composer) anyway.

Your git repository now has all the files needed to run the website directly within it and so you can now simply upload your website to your shared host as you usually do.

I wrote up full details here: https://akrabat.com/using-composer-with-shared-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

Download the Slim Framework from here https://php-download.com/package/slim/slim then just add `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');`